# Disabling MacOS Ventura Shortcut to Move Window to the Bottom or Top

Tags: keyboard, windows, window-manager

Since updating to MacOS Ventura, I cannot find any way to disable some keyboard shortcuts. The 'move window' shortcuts appear to work now but I cannot find where to modify or disable these in the Settings. I have followed all online instructions to get to the new location of they keyboard shortcuts but cannot find these listed.

These shortcuts conflict with many other common shortcuts in other applications and any help will be appreciated.

Below are the keyboard shortcuts and screenshots of the settings where I would expect to see these.

### Shortcut 1 - Move window down

> Option (or Alt) `⌥` **+** Control (or Ctrl) `⌃` **+** Down `↓`

This behaves exactly the same as 'Move Window to Left side of screen' but it moves it down, so that the window takes up the bottom half of the screen.

### Shortcut 2 - Move window Up

Similar to above but it moves the window to the top half of the screen.

> Option (or Alt) `⌥` **+** Control (or Ctrl) `⌃` **+** Up `↑`

[image: Keyboard shortcut]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No, I just can't use some shortcuts anymore which is very frustrating.